# What steps are included when Jmeter measuring JDBC response time

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am using Jmeter to send JDBC requests to a database.

I was wondering what steps are included when measuring response time.

For example, I am sending a select request to database.

I was the first query response time is larger than ours and I am assuming the first requests require establishing connection to the database and the rest requests are using connection pooling.

I want to know what Jmeter has done to the result set. Does Jmeter just iterate through all rows? Does it fetch all columns values? Can I know which part of source code does Jmeter actually execute when calculating response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically everything is included, to wit:

1. Open (or get) the connection
2. Execute query
3. Close the connection

You can check the details in [JDBCSampler.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/jdbc/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/sampler/JDBCSampler.java) or enable debug logging for JDBC protocol by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
log_level.jmeter.protocol.jdbc=DEBUG
```

or passing it to JMeter startup script via `-J` command-line argument as

```
jmeter -Jlog_level.jmeter.protocol.jdbc=DEBUG -n -t test.jmx ...
```

[image: JDBC JMeter]

The whole [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is being returned from the query to JMeter, you can work with it via [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or scripting, see [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide for more details.